# Get fgetc under GNU/Linux to process Mac OS CR

Tags: c, linux, macos

Under GNU/Linux, with the following file 'foo.csv' (of course *\r* are Mac carriage returns):

```
0,1,2,3\r
4,5,6,7\r
6,9,10,11\r
```

The *fgets* function returns the whole file as one line. How can I specify that *fgets* should process \r as newline ?

Example of C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        FILE *stream = fopen(argv[1],"r");
        char tmp[1024];
        int i=0;
        while (fgets (tmp, 1024, stream) != NULL) {
                printf("line %d\n", i);
                i++;
        }
}
```

I would like to avoid a pass to transform *\r* => *\n*.

Comment: Have you tried using the `"rt"` mode with `fopen`?  And why does your title say `fgetc` when your question is about `fgets`?

Comment: I don't know a priori what is going to be the newline of the file... 
I fixed the typo in the title, thanks!

Comment: Mac OS X uses the same `\n` as Linux and every other remotely UNIX-like OS. Mac OS 9 (pre-2001) was the last to use `\r`. What you are seeing is `\r\n` (note that a newline follows each `\r`) which comes from WinDOS. (Edited question.)

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I disagree with your edit; your comment is pure supposition.  A file could have been transferred from Mac 9 to a computer running OS X or Linux.  A comment is the right place for that sort of observation.  And in fact, because "The `fgets` function returns the whole file as one line." I'd have to say you're wrong about `"\r\n"`, so I'm reverting it.

Comment: @BenVoigt If there were no newline characters, `foo.csv` would never be rendered like that by an editor or terminal. And few people used the older Macs to generate CSV files. Calling it "OS X" is simply incorrect.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: It probably *isn't* rendered like that in the editor.  The OP probably did that to emphasize which control characters are present.  Fact is, "The `fgets` function returns the whole file as one line." does wonders to clarify the actual situation.

Comment: Well, I have users which are still using \r ...

Comment: Added to my bucket list: write a virus which does nothing but convert line endings of documents to `\r`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use `getdelim` as described on this page:
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html

Note that `getdelim` (and `getline`) works differently from fgets, so you need to change your code around a little bit - in particular, you need to start with a `char *ptr = NULL` and `size = 0`; then pass those as `getdelim(&ptr, &size, '\r', stream);` - and when you are finished reading the whole file, call `free(ptr);`.

Edit: To find out what line ending the file has:

```
int lineending(FILE *f)
{
    int ch;
    long fpos = ftell(f);
    while((ch = fgetc(f)) != EOF)
        if (ch == '\r' || ch == '\n')
            break;
    fseek(f, fpos, CUR_BEGIN);
    return ch;
}
```

There you go.

Comment: getline are not able to process both at the same time :/

Comment: @Sylvestre: "Process both at the same time" is not the question you asked.

Comment: No, if you want to be able to read files created in a multi-system environment, then you'd need to either write a function that does something similar to getdelim() but takes, for example, a string of characters, all of which are line endings, or read the first line of the file and see what it ends with, and then pass that as the argument to getdelim. I'd be tempted to do the first one. If you confirm that this is what you are looking for, I can amend my answer

Comment: @MatsPetersson: So, I guess there is no way to do that out of the box :/
Anyway, thanks to you two.

Comment: No, but if you want to write a very simple function that scans the line, it's about thee lines of not very difficult code. See my edit:

Answer (score 1):

On both Linux and OSX, you can call `getdelim`, which allows you to specify the delimiter character.